# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I am totally stumped on this one. I am getting a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error - but I can't figure out why. This is the code that I have:

```
        public class PlayerProfile
    {
        public List<Profile> PlayerINfo = new List<Profile>();


        public void LoadProfiles(string path)
        {
            XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
            PlayerINfo = new List<Profile>();

// This is where I get the error:
            PlayerINfo = (from profiles in xmlDoc.Root.Element("OnlineProfile").Elements("Player")
                              select new Profile
                              {
                                  Name = (string)profiles.Element("Name"),
                                  Sex = (string)profiles.Element("Sex"),
                                  Avatar = (string)profiles.Element("Avatar").Attribute("path") ?? "",
                                  Created = (DateTime)profiles.Element("Created")
                              }).ToList();


        }
    }
```

Here is my Profile class:

```
    public class Profile
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public string Avatar { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

}
```

**EDIT - Adding the XML file code:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OnlineProfile>
  <Player>
    <Name>Stacey</Name>
    <Sex>Female</Sex>
    <Avatar path="/images/Picture.png" />
    <Ratio>
      <Win>0</Win>
      <Loss>0</Loss>
      <Abandoned>0</Abandoned>
    </Ratio>
    <Created>6/19/2011</Created>
  </Player>

</OnlineProfile>
```

Comment: It also loads the XML file just fine

Comment: Are you sure there are no spelling mistakes anywhere? All the cases match and everything?

Comment: maybe post a sample of the xml document

Comment: As an aside, you've initialized PlayerInfo to an empty list twice before setting it to the result of the XML query. Those first two initializations are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this: `from profiles in xmlDoc.Element("OnlineProfile").Elements("Player")` instead of from `profiles in xmlDoc.Root.Element("OnlineProfile").Elements("Player")`

From the XML you posted "OnlineProfile" is your Root element, so the child elements you expect arent there.

Comment: I just added the XML in. If i remove profiles.Element("Avatar").Attribute("path") I still get the error.

Comment: If i were to add in two roots - "OnlineProfile" and "LocalProfile" would I want to use Root at that time?

Comment: Think of root as accessing the inside of a xml element. So if you wanted onlineprofile and localprofile to be on the same level you could put them inside another element for example, playerprofiles and call root from playerprofiles and have access to both

Comment: PROTIP:  Don't answer questions on stack overflow via your mobile phone. As you can tell from my comments, you make no sense.

Answer (score 4):

```
from profiles in xmlDoc.Root.Element("OnlineProfile").Elements("Player")
```

This is the problem - `OnlineProfile` *is* your root element, just do

```
from profiles in xmlDoc.Root.Elements("Player")
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried this out + solved this in visual studio.  I see the people above beat me to it.  Another way to achieve this is:

```
xmlDoc.Element("OnlineProfile").Elements("Player")
```

---

This is what I posted prior to the Xml becomming available...

here's a good candidate for that error

```
 (string)profiles.Element("Avatar").Attribute("...
```

").Attribute would cause an error.  You need to check for null.

e.g.

```
   = profiles.Element("Avatar") != null ? (string)profiles.Element("Avatar").Attribute("... : null;
```

do you definitely have an element called Avatar in your Xml file.  Did the file load in correctly?

Comment: I do have the element called Avatar in my XML file. I will update the post in one moment with the XML. The file also does show that it is loading correctly. I removed all of the items except for the Name from the linq query and still got the error.

Comment: load in some XML from string if you could so that people can cut'n'paste your code easily.

Comment: @Stacey: another way of solving this posted above.